# TextBox text Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a `LineSeries` to which I am binding the data from an `ObservableCollection` of the type `ChartData`. Now, In my UI, I have a `TextBox` in which I need to show the Y value of the series. How do I bind the `Value` property to the `TextBox`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<ChartData> lineSeries1Data = new ObservableCollection<ChartData>();
        simChart.DataContext = lineSeries1Data;
    }
public class ChartData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DateTime _Name;
    double _Value;

    public DateTime Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
            _Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }      
}
```

This is my XAML for the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Name="TxtSignal1Vh1" DataContext="lineSeries1Data" Text="{Binding ChartData.Value}" />
```

Comment: `Value` property of what, `ChartData`?

Comment: Your goal isn't clear, you have many `ChartData` in `ObservableCollection` but only one `TextBox`. Which `Value` should be displayed?

Comment: I have a `Chart` and I have a `TextBox`. The `Chart` x,y values are bound to the two properties in the `ChartData` class through an `ObservableCollection`. Now, I want to show the y-value of the chart in the `TextBox`. The literal name of y-Value is "Value" property.

Comment: @Abhishek simchart.Datacontext=lineSeries1Data;  

whats simchart??

Comment: @AbhinavSharma : simChart is the name of the `LineSeries`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Working Code,Create a Usercontrol consisting of Chart+textboxes and then binds its Datacontext to  respective observable collection.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        observableCollection<DataChart>1st=new observableCollection<DataChart>();
        observableCollection<DataChart>2nd=new observableCollection<DataChart>();
        win.DataContext = (1st Observable Collection)
        lose.DataContext=(2nd Observable Collection)
    }
```

MainWindows xaml

```
<Grid>
    <this:UserControl1 x:Name="win"  Margin="10,21,325,144"/>
    <this:UserControl1 x:Name="lose" Margin="275,21,10,144"/>
</Grid>
```

UserControl xaml

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox  Text="{Binding Path=Value}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164"/>
   <TextBox   Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If I have more than one chart, then what would be the approach?I would have to set the `DataContext` for each of the charts right?How will I set the `DataContext` for the `TextBox` then?

Comment: So how do I set the `DataContext` for the `TextBox` then?Can you give an example which sets the `DataContext` directly to the control instead of it's parent/ancestor?

Comment: @Abhishek Please elaborate your requirements as i am not sure what exactly you want....

Comment: I have two Charts. I am setting the `DataContext` of the two charts explicitly to two `ObservableCollection`s. Normally, if only a single chart is there, I can set the `DataContext` to this in the `Constructor`. But, since I have two charts, I am setting each of the chart's `DataContext` to their own `ObservableCollection`s. Now, I have two `TextBox`es in which I have to display the Y-Value of the two charts. So how do I bind the second property in the `ObservableCollection` (which is the Y-Value) to the `TextBox`?

Comment: Its just an Idea, but how about creating a UserControl consisting of
chart+textBoxes then binding Usercontrol`s datacontext with its respective observable collection!!!!